# Need a query to find count of a column record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this,

```
 ProductId     CategoryID     bIsPrimary
     1             5              1
     1             6              0
     1             7              0
     2             18             1
     2             19             1
```

I need a output like this,

```
 ProductID        PrimaryCategoryCount
     1                    1
     2                    2
```

Basically i need to find the the number of primary categories for each product.

Comment: And we need to see what you've tried so far.  Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service.  **EDIT:** *sigh*, apparently it is

Comment: because I was able to spend less time writing an answer for this question (5 seconds?) than it would take to argue with the original poster about what is an is not a good question

Comment: @Tom: I agree with you , this is not a suitable question. I have also written the same query that you wrote but I was not sure of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ProductId, COUNT(*)
FROM SomeTable
WHERE bIsPrimary <> 0
GROUP BY ProductId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
ProductId
,sum(case when bIsPrimary = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as PrimaryCategoryCount
from
Table
group by
ProductId
```

or

```
SELECT
ProductId
,count(CategoryId)
from
Table
where bIsPrimiary = 1
group by ProductId
```

Both will provide you the same result. Pick up one which suits you more or is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductId, COUNT(bIsPrimary)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ProductId
```

This is how I'd do it. WHERE clause isn't necessary here if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: `Basically i need to find the the number of primary categories for each product.` So `where` is needed, and is similar to the `Tom` answer

Comment: This one will count also rows in which bsIsPrimary = 0 and he doesn't want it.

Comment: Excuse me for my mistake. Tom's query is indeed correct then.